# Replace values in a dataframe in python with the dictionary, where the dictionary values are lists

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

msft = yf.Ticker("MSFT")

df= msft.recommendations

df['ToGrade_new'] = df['To Grade'].str.lower().str.replace('[^\w\s]','')

new_df = df['ToGrade_new'].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts().reset_index()

new_df.columns = ['Word', 'Frequency']

newdict = {'VGood': ['buy', 'strong'], 'Good': ['moderate', 'overweight'], 'Okay': ['hold', 'equalweight', 'market','neutral'], 'Bad': ['underperform','moderatesell','underweight'], 'VBad':['sell']}
```

I need help here. I want to replace the Word column in the new_df dataframe with the words I have for keys in the newdict dictionary. Any help would be appreciated.

If new_df looks like this

Word        Frequency

buy            121

overweight       82
...

then it should be replaced by

Word        Frequency

VGood          121

Good            82
...

Comment: What do you expect your result to be? If `new_df['Word']` is `'VGood'`, e.g., what would you like it to be mapped to? Also it would be nice if you could hardcode the value of `df` so that people who don't have and don't want to install `yfinance` can answer your question (Remember, a [mre] should also be _minimal_)

Comment: What's your expected output? Could be as simple as `df["Word"].map(new_dict)`, but it's not possible to tell given what you've provided.

Comment: Please update your post. Do not add clarifying information in comments.

Comment: You need your dictionary in the opposite order.  You want `newdict['buy']` to return `'VGood'`.  Then, it's just a simple lookup.

Comment: Thats what I figured, it will have to be flipped. Is there no way to look up a value in a dataframe where the value is a a dictionary value in a list. Generally asking since I didnt see anyone do it